# Invalid hook call 3 times in the same file

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I don't know why, but my original react app file stopped working. It was missing sanity/core for some reason, even though it had been working fine the past week. Its my first time using react app and sanity, so instead I just made a new folder and installed sanity from the start.

I transferred all of my necessary files, though accidentally had my original react app folder inside when I copied and pasted- I deleted it after making a new react app folder where I installed react-app in that one.

I've fixed any pathway issues, but nothing is showing up now when I access localhost:3000. I'm getting this error thrice:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

All three reference react.development.js:1476, so I assume I'm getting this error because I have three copies of react in the same app? I noticed I have 2 `node_modules` folders, one in my overall folder for the website (which contains the sanity project), and another one thats greyed out in my react app folder. Would deleting one fix the issue, cause more issues, or is there something else causing this issue?

Not sure what code to paste in here, but I'm happy to add any required information.

EDIT: I've only used hooks twice, the first one has been working fine, but the second one hasn't so if either have any issue, it will be this one (though its not in the react.development.js file):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './about.css'
import sanityClient from '../client';
          
export default function About() {

    const [aboutData, setAbout] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        sanityClient
            .fetch(`*[_type=="website_images"]{
                alt,
                about{
                    asset->{
                        _id,
                        url
                    }
                }
            }`)
            .then((data) => setAbout(data))
            .catch(console.error);
    }, [] );

    return (
        <main className="main-about">
            <div className="about-body">
                <div className="about-title">
                    <div className="title-line-left"></div>
                    <h2>about</h2>
                    <div className="title-line-right"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="about-text">
                    <p className="pronouns">(they/them)</p>
                    <p>The Japanese city and the Prefecture of Hiroshima may have been devastated by the atomic bomb over 76 years ago, but today, this site of the destruction is one of the top tourist destinations in the entire country. Statistics released by the nation's tourist agency revealed that around 363,000 visitors went to the metropolis during 2012, with Americans making up the vast majority of that figure, followed by Australians and Chinese.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            {aboutData && aboutData.map((website_images, index) => (
                <figure className="photo-position">
                    <img src="{website_images.about.asset.url}" alt="{website_images.alt}" className="about-photo"></img>
                </figure>
            ))}
        </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to help you without any code. In most cases you got a hook installed/executed after an `if` statement. Maybe you can reduce the execution path to a minimum and then post the code in here.

Comment: I just edited the post and added some code of a hook that hasn't been working for me yet, used to fetch data from sanity backend

Comment: What get's returned form you're fetch promise? I tested it in https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-shirley-fpdtiz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark and it seems to work fine? Just replaced the fetch with an Promise.resolve and the initial state of `aboutData` to an array

Comment: I'm making an art portfolio, so I need to fetch images that I have stored in my backend (sanity client) onto the website, and their corresponding data. At the moment, I'm getting a white screen for the whole website so nothing is showing up

Comment: Your code as posted works perfectly fine. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to create a reproducable example. Otherwise I can't help you

Comment: Yeah the code seems to be fine, was definitely an issue with the react folders as suspected. I was able to avoid the issue by recovering an older version of my website that only had a backend issue instead that I just fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to avoid having this issue, but I'll post this response I got off the site here for anyone who comes here looking for an answer:

"It is almost certainly because you have three versions of react. Try deleting your node_modules folder, removing all but one instance of react, & run `npm install`."